# Calculate the flux of $G(x,y,z)=x(1-z)\hat{k}$ through a cube

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-fields

Calculate the flux of $G(x,y,z)=x(1-z)\hat{k}$ through the cube with the vertices 
$(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)$ with an outward pointing normal vector.

I don't really have an idea what to do, so far  I just calculated the normal vector, $\hat{N}=\frac{\nabla G}{|\nabla G|}$=$\frac{(0,0,-x)}{x}=(0,0,-1)$.

So $\int\int_s F \bullet dS$=$\int\int_D(F_1 \frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial(u,v)}+F_2 \frac{\partial(x,z)}{\partial(u,v)}+F_3 \frac{\partial(y,x)}{\partial(u,v)}) du dv$

Comment: If you want to go the route of the surface flux integral you break the cube into six faces each with their own normal vectors, five of these integrals will be zero leaving only one to evaluate. Also that equation for the normal vector is for the surface not the vector field in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the integral up in to six separate integrals over the 6 faces of the cube, where the faces are indicated for convenience by $x=0$ etc. on the integral signs.

$$\int \int_{x=0} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{(-i)}dS + \int \int_{x=1} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{i}\,dS + \int \int_{y=0} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{(-j)}dS
+\int \int_{y=1} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{j}\,dS $$
$$+\int \int_{z=0} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{(-k)}dS 
+ \int \int_{z=1} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{k}\,dS$$

The dot products pick out the components of $\mathbf{G}$ and it is only the $z$ component which is non-zero so the first 4 integrals are zero. Of the remaining 2 integrals, $$\int \int_{z=1} \mathbf{G}.\mathbf{k}\,dS$$ is zero because $z=1$ on that face. That leaves one double integral to perform on the $z=0$ face where $\mathbf{G}=x\mathbf{k}$ and $dS=dx\,dy$

$$\int \int_{z=0}(x\mathbf{k}).(-\mathbf{k})\,dS = 
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=1} (-x) \,dx\,dy$$

Also note that the Divergence Theorem could be considered as an alternative approach to solving this.